# Get text between two strings Regex VB.Net

Tags: html, regex, vb.net

I really have serious problems with regex. I need to get all text between 2 strings, in this case that strings are `<span class="user user-role-registered-member">` and `</span>`.

I googled pretty much questions (some of them are on StackOverFlow), and watched YouTube tutorials, still can't get it.

This is the code that i think would work, but i don't know why it doesn't.

```
Dim mystring As String = "<br>Terms of Service<br></br>Developers<br>"

Dim pattern1 As String = "(?<=<br>)(.*?)(?=<br>)"
Dim pattern2 As String = "(?<=</br>)(.*)(?=<br>)"

Dim m1 As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(mystring, pattern1)
Dim m2 As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(mystring, pattern2)
MsgBox(m1(0).ToString)
MsgBox(m2(0).ToString)
```

Ok, so this code works pretty well....with `<br>`. I tried to change pattern1 and pattern2's `<br>` with span but it doesn't work. I know that i am making a mistake here, but i don't know where/how.

Any answer will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the job easily and beautifully. It *won't* return a match when there is no text inside the span, so you do not need to worry about empty matches. It will however return groups with only whitespace in them.

```
<span class=""user user-role-registered-member"">(.+)</span>
```

Test it out [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3Cspan%20class%3D%22%22user%20user-role-registered-member%22%22%3E(.%2B)%3C%2Fspan%3E&i=%3Cspan%20class%3D%22%22user%20user-role-registered-member%22%22%3EIf%20this%20is%20working%2C%20the%20text%20in%20this%20span%20should%20be%20in%20a%20captured%20group.%3C%2Fspan%3E).

Comment: @Stefan Đorđević beware, this will fail if there are multiple closing span tags..make it non greedy using `.+?`

Comment: Easy for you, not readable for others. `Xml` approach is most clear, easy and readable, sorry

Comment: @Fabio all I did was answer the question. The question asked me for a Regex, and I gave one. I'd have gone for the XML parser route too, but I knew that *someone* would  mention it and decided to answer the question instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it with XML:

```
Dim s As String = "<span class=""user user-role-registered-member"">Keyboard</span>"
Dim doc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
doc.LoadXml(s)
Console.WriteLine(doc.FirstChild.InnerText) ' Outputs: "Keyboard"
```

There are reasons given for not trying to parse HTML with regexes at [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Answer (score 2):

Thank you very much for answers. I found answer by myself (thanks to Evil Tak i got an idea).

```
Dim findtext As String = "(?<=<span class=""user user-role-registered-member"">)(.*?)(?=</span>)"
Dim myregex As String = "<span class=""user user-role-registered-member"">Keyboard</span>"
Dim doregex As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(myregex, findtext)
MsgBox(doregex(0).ToString)
```

StackOverFlow is so powerful...♥

Comment: You don't need to use lookaheads and lookbehinds, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

Use Explicit capture groups. The following should do the job:

```
Dim exp = "<span class=""user user-role-registered-member"">(?<GRP>.*)</span>"
Dim M = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(YourInputString, exp, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture)
If M.Groups("GRP").Value <> "" Then
  Return M.Groups("GRP").Value
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Your text is `xml`, so why to hack a strings with `Regex` if you can do it in readable and clear way.
With [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384460.aspx)

```vb
Dim htmlPage As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(downloadedHtmlPage)

Dim className As String = "user user-role-registered-member"
Dim value As String = 
    htmlPage.Descendants("span").
    Where(Function(span) span.Attribute("class").Value.Equals(className)).
    FirstOrDefault().
    Value
```

And with [Accessing XML in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384974.aspx)

```vb
Dim htmlPage As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(downloadedHtmlPage)

Dim className As String = "user user-role-registered-member"
Dim value As String = 
    htmlPage...<span>.
    Where(Function(span) span.@class.Value.Equals(className)).
    FirstOrDefault().
    Value
```